# How can i remove items from the basket automatically if the customer added product is out of stock in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php, magento2.4

scenario - the customer added products to the basket and logged out. After sometime he again logged in, now when he checked his minicart or cart i need to remove the products which are out of stock and show the messege [xxx],[yyy] products removed due to out of stock.How can i achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a custom action on LoginPost.

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost" type="Cpy\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost" />
```

In `\Cpy\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost` you can access the `$customer` variable after the authentication. From that variable you should be able to get the cart and mini cart of the customer and to modify them as you want.

To display the message : you can use

```
$this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                    __('we removed xxx product due to out of stock');
```